# How to delete downloaded files on Android TV

Tags: internal-storage, file-management, android-tv

I have a Sony Bravia TV with Android.

When trying to install a new app from the Play store it says I have to free up some space, as my storage is full.
When checking storage in the settings, it says the cca 5.5GB are in the `Downloads` folder.
But I have no option to delete it, as there is nothing like a file manager.
I also cannot download any file manager, or cleaner etc. as it won't install anything, cause the storage is full.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there seemed to be enough space (0.9GB) to install a small file manager app (about 30MB), I had to:
- clear caches from several apps
- deleting stored data from several apps
- uninstall some default app updates
After that I got about 1.6GB of free space, and just then it allowed me to install a File manager, where I was able to browse to the Download folder and remove unnecessary data.

I don't think this is a real solution, there must be another way, but this was the way that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to settings -> Storage then clear the cache it may give you save space to install any of the file manager and delete the files which are not needed.

Comment: There is almost 1GB free space but it still says there is no space to download an app